# Haskell AST Incomplete Location Information

Tags: parsing, haskell, abstract-syntax-tree

I've been trying to build Haskell AST's so that I can find out which AST nodes exist on which lines of a source file. So far, I am using `Language.Haskell.Parser` and `Language.Haskell.Syntax`, which seem to work fairly well. I can generate a tree, then run through each part of it get out the line number using `srcLine loc` (where `loc` is a SrcLoc).

However, I am running into issues when the parsed file looks like this:

FILE 1

```
1| rangeLeq :: Integer -> NonnegRange
2| rangeLeq n =
3|   Range BoundaryBelowAll (BoundaryAbove n)
```

The file could easily have been written like this:

FILE 2

```
1| rangeLeq :: Integer -> NonnegRange
2| rangeLeq n = Range BoundaryBelowAll (BoundaryAbove n)
```

The problem is that the parser sees these two as equivalent. It does not assign a SrcLoc to everything, only to certain parts of the AST. So what I end up with is the following output for both file 1 and file 2:

```
line 1: HsTypeSig
        |--HsIdent (rangeLeq)
        |--HsQualType
           |--HsContext
           |--HsTyFun
              |--HsTyCon
                 |--HsUnQual
                    |--HsIdent (Integer)
              |--HsTyCon
                 |--HsUnQual
                    |--HsIdent (NonnegRange)
line 2: HsMatch
        |--HsIdent (rangeLeq)
        |--HsPVar
           |--HsIdent (n)
        |--HsUnGuardedRhs
           |--HsApp
              |--HsApp
                 |--HsCon
                    |--HsUnQual
                       |--HsIdent (Range)
                 |--HsCon
                    |--HsUnQual
                       |--HsIdent (BoundaryBelowAll)
              |--HsParen
                 |--HsApp
                    |--HsCon
                       |--HsUnQual
                          |--HsIdent (BoundaryAbove)
                    |--HsVar
                       |--HsUnQual
                          |--HsIdent (n)
```

So the issue here is that there is no location information on most of the nodes, so it sees the function definition (`HsMatch`) as a single line. In case it is unclear, The `HsMatch` represents `rangeLeq n = Range BoundaryBelowAll (BoundaryAbove n)` in the code. Since the only part of the AST that comes with a `SrcLoc` is the `HsMatch` itself, the parser is assuming that all parts of the `HsMatch` are on the same line.

`tl;dr` How can I get a correct parse, such that lines in the source file that are split unnecessarily still get tagged with the appropriate line? Id est, I want a parse that tags *every single node* with a `SrcLoc`, not just certain nodes.

Comment: if the Language.Haskell.* modules are not working for you, perhaps try out the libraries behind this project: http://haskelltools.org  Looks like their code is available both on Hackage and github.

Comment: It won't be possible - [the majority](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-1.0.2.0/docs/Language-Haskell-Syntax.html#t:HsExp) of expression constructors simply do not contain an `SrcLoc`. I don't think this parser aims to give the user completely accurate line numbers - even ghc doesn't get this quite right all the time.

Comment: I realize that the constructors do not contain SrcLoc information. What I'm looking for is either a different parser or an alternate method of determining the line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[`haskell-src-exts`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts) has a location tag ([`SrcSpanInfo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.18.2/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-SrcLoc.html#t:SrcSpanInfo) by default) on [every subexpression](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.18.2/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html#t:Exp); it should have enough detail to disambiguate your two example cases.

Comment: Using `Language.Haskell.Exts.Parser.parse` , I still get the same problem. I end up with a `Module` rather than an `HsModule`, and there still is no location information on every node.